# Why I'm getting this error when I run this script on firefox? What can I change in the code to fix this?

Tags: python, firefox, instagram

```
import json
import sys

arguments = sys.argv
try:
    file = arguments[1]
    iters = (int)(arguments[2])
    with open(file) as s:
        d = json.load(s)
    m = {}
    for x in d['log']['entries']:
        ls = json.loads(x['response']['content']['text'])['items']
        for y in ls:
            m[y['code']] = y['like_count']
    sorted_m = dict(sorted(m.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True))
    count = 1
    for x,y in sorted_m.items():
        link = "https://www.instagram.com/p/" + x + "/"
        print(link,y)
        count += 1
        if (count > iters):
            break
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

This is the error I'm getting after running this in the firefox console.

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module"
```

Comment: In your Firefox console, you can only execute JavaScript. This however is Python.

Comment: Thank you for responding bro. I was trying to sort instagram posts by views as mentioned in the following website: https://theuntoldapps.github.io/sorting-instagram-posts-by-likes/.  @HolgerJust

Comment: But I'm unable to do the last 2 steps. Where should I run the script cause when I try to run it gets me errors bro. Can you help me out? @HolgerJust